# How to use an array in a zip function using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, 7zip

I am still pretty new to scripting and "programming" at all. if you miss any information here let me know.
This is my working zip function:

```
 $folder = "C:\zipthis\"
 $destinationFilePath = "C:\_archive\zipped"

   function create-7zip{
    param([string] $folder, 
    [String] $destinationFilePath)
    write-host $folder $destinationFilePath
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7zG.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$destinationFilePath", "$folder";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
    }

Get-ChildItem $folder | ? { $_.PSIsContainer} | % {
     write-host $_.BaseName $_.Name;
     $dest= [System.String]::Concat($destPath,$_.Name,".zip");
     (create-7zip $_.FullName $dest)
     } 


create-7zip $folder $destinationFilePath
```

now I want him to zip special folders which I already sorted out :

```
get-childitem "C:\zipme\" | where-Object {$_.name -eq "www" -or $_.name -eq "sql" -or $_.name -eq "services"}
```

This small function finds the 3 folders I need called `www, sql and services`. But I didn't manage to insert this into my zip function, so that exactly this folders are zipped and put into `C:\_archive\zipped`

Because a string is used instead of an array, he tried always to look for a folder called wwwsqlservice which is not there. I tried to put an array using `@(www,sql,services)` but i had no success, so whats the right way, if there is one?
It should compatible with powershell 2.0, no ps3.0 cmdlets or functions please.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps try `@("www","sql","services")`? I expect powershell would give you an error without making those array elements strings first. If this is helpful I can post a more fleshed out answer with an example.

Comment: that's what I did, changed the parameter to array and then he tries to make one name like wwwsqlservices  and can't find it.

Comment: What is the proper syntax for passing multiple directories to 7zip for compression?

Comment: i guess i need something like % (foreach) and then let the function run 3 times, for every folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really simple example of what you want to do, removed from the context of your function.  It assumes that your destination folders already exist (You can just use `Test-Path` and `New-Item` to create them if they don't), and that you're using 7z.exe.

```
$directories = @("www","sql","services")  
$archiveType = "-tzip"
foreach($dir in $directories)
{
    # Use $dir to update the destination each loop to prevent overwrites!
    $sourceFilePath = "mySourcePath\$dir"
    $destinationFilePath = "myTargetPath\$dir"

    cmd /c "$pathToZipExe a $archiveType $destinationFilePath $sourceFilePath"
}
```

Overall it looks like you got pretty close to a solution, with some minor changes needed to support the foreach loop. If you're confident that `create-7zip` works fine for a single folder, you can substitute that for the `cmd /c` line above. Here's a listing of some handy [example usages](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) for 7zip on the command line.